# For Loop not working properly (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I've been trying to get this program to work properly. It does compile, however instead of prompting the user for input, it states something incorrect.

The prompt:

> Ask the user for 10 course marks (from 0 to 100) and afterwards state (in a label) how many were passing marks.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mark;
    int passinggrades = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Mark:";
        cin >> mark;
        while(mark >= 50)
        {
            passinggrades++;
        }
    }
    cout << j << " of your marks were passing grades.";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The loop condition is wrong:

```
for (int i=0; i>10;i++)
```

Reverse the comparison sign

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
```

Also , you probably want `if` in this line:

```
while(mark >= 50)
```

Change to

```
if(mark >= 50)
```

Even the output line is wrong. There is no `j` in your code. Do this:

```
cout << passinggrades << " of your marks were passing grades.";
```

Comment: `cout << j << " of your marks were passing grades.";` - `j` should be `passinggrades` also.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i>10;i++)
```

You start at `i = 0` and you perform the loop while `i > 10` (which is never, since it is 0).

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted

```
    if(mark >= 50)
```

instead of the infinite loop

```
    while(mark >= 50)
```

Also, `i<10` like the others said.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues:
ONE:
When you say:

```
while(mark >= 50)
{
    passinggrades++;
}
```

An input of 50+ would make your program get stuck in the look forever. Instead use:

```
if(mark >= 50)
{
    passinggrades++;
}
```

TWO:

instead of `i>10` in the for loop, use `i<10`

THREE: (Thanks ctor for the comment)

`j` is not defined and should be replaced with `passinggrades`.

Comment: `j` is also undefined.